# Fetching data from Flipkart API

Tags: php, web-scraping

I want to fetch product details from Flipkart using their API (strictly in PHP). I want to create a search bar where user will enter any 'query' and that'll simply show relevant search results from Flipkart. I don't have any idea.

```
    <form action="test.php" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="searchdata">
        <label for="searchdata">Search Product</label>

        <input id="search" type="submit" value="Search">

    </form>

    <?php
    // Get Web Page Data using URL

    echo "Flipkart";

    if(isset($_GET['searchdata'])){

        $search= $_GET['searchdata'];
        $search= strtolower($search);
        //space to plus
        $search=str_replace(" ","+",$search);


        $web_page_data =  file_get_contents("https://flipkart.com/search?q=".$search);


    echo "Data Output of above link"."<br/>";
        echo "--------------------------------"."<br/>";

    // We need particular data from the page and not the whole content
        $item_list =explode('<div class="items-wrap">', $web_page_data); //from entire web page it will split based on word <div class="items-wrap">

    //Item list is an array so print_r
    //print_r($item_list);


            $request = "https://affiliate-api.flipkart.net/affiliate/api/yuganshch.json";
            $response = file_get_contents($request);
            $results = json_decode($response, TRUE);


        foreach ($results['data'] as $key => $itemdata) {
            $price = $itemdata['Best_Price'];
            $product_link = $itemdata['Uri'];

            echo $seller."<br/>".$price."<br/>".$product_link."<br/><br/>";
        }



    }

else {
    echo "<p>No Product Found, Please Search Again</p>";
}
```

Could you please help me with this? It's not working. Showing error in argument of foreach() function:

This is the error:

> Notice: Undefined index: data in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/testing/test.php on line 70
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/testing/test.php on line 70
>
> Line 70 : foreach ($results['data'] as $key => $itemdata)

Then $results['data'] should be replaced by which variable?

Comment: Quick test looks like you have issue after parsing json response. There doesn't seem to be a "data" element in json (`$results['data']`), so `foreach` has trouble iterating over the undefined index.

Comment: I only see "title", "description" and "apiGroups" at that endpoint instead of "data"

Comment: Tell us the error (s) and show us `$results`.  If you aren't going to use `$key` in your loop don't bother declaring it at the start of the loop.

Comment: Then `$results['data']` should be replaced by which variable? @JasonW

Comment: probably just $results to get top level of JSON response.

Comment: This is still now working @JasonW

`foreach ($results as $key => $itemdata) {
            $price = $itemdata['Best_Price'];
            $product_link = $itemdata['Uri'];

            echo $seller."<br/>".$price."<br/>".$product_link."<br/><br/>";
        }`

Comment: **Error :** Illegal string offset

Comment: The $results is coming from the affiliate url. I think it is giving you different JSON than you are anticipating. Maybe `$results = json_decode($response, TRUE);` should be `$results = json_decode($web_page_data, TRUE);` so you're getting true search results instead of affiliate endpoint.

Comment: That's not an issue @JasonW - Error is : **Invalid argument supplied for foreach()**

Comment: The issue here is search results don't have a clean API endpoint. I don't know anything about the service you're connecting to, but maybe they have a direct API to use. I hooked up the HTTP Proxy Fiddler, and it may be that you have to just parse through the HTML (http://htmlparsing.com/php.html). It won't be easy since there isn't much identifying elements due to react that they use.

Comment: Again, please show us `$results`.

Comment: `$results = json_decode($web_page_data, TRUE);`